# Django-uni-form highlight active field

Tags: jquery, django, uniform

can anyone help me with Django Uni-form module, I don't understand how can i highlight active field. I know it depend from jQuery, i've included theese files

```
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}uni_form/uni-form.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I still get [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAwSC.png) error in FireBug:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first load Jquery, and then the libraries which depend on it.

Comment: you are right, that error in FireBug gone, thanks, now I'm stuck, I dont know where is a trouble:(